# How to compare and rate Virtual CPUs?

Tags: linux, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, hosting, hypervisor

I have got two virtual Servers on different Hosters and asking myself how I can get a clue of the CPU Performance. Which metrics can I have a look at and how can I get a feeling for it so that I can say Server 1 is like 1 GHz and Server 2 only 500 MHz?

If i run lscpu on **vServer 1** I get

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                1
On-line CPU(s) list:   0
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 85
Model name:            Intel Xeon Processor (Skylake)
Stepping:              4
CPU MHz:               2099.998
BogoMIPS:              4199.99
Hypervisor vendor:     KVM
Virtualization type:   full
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              4096K
L3 cache:              16384K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0
Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch invpcid_single rsb_ctxsw retpoline kaiser fsgsbase bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm mpx avx512f rdseed adx smap clwb avx512cd xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 arat
```

whereas on **vServer 2** I get

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                1
On-line CPU(s) list:   0
Thread(s) pro Kern:    1
Kern(e) pro Socket:    1
Socket(s):             1
NUMA-Knoten:           1
Anbieterkennung:       GenuineIntel
Prozessorfamilie:      15
Modell:                6
Model name:            Common KVM processor
Stepping:              1
CPU MHz:               3066.776
BogoMIPS:              6133.55
Hypervisor-Anbieter:   KVM
Virtualisierungstyp:   voll
L1d Cache:             32K
L1i Cache:             32K
L2 Cache:              4096K
L3 Cache:              16384K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0
Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx lm constant_tsc nopl xtopology pni cx16 x2apic hypervisor lahf_lm retpoline kaiser
```

I know that vServer 2 is really slow whereas vServer 1 is fast for me, when running things like apt update and apt upgrade. The lscpu only shows the hardware but how do I get to know about the CPU limitations of my Hoster?

Comment: execute command "# cat /proc/cpuinfo ". you will get more details about frequency of servers.

Comment: check parameter "CPU MHz". Available memory on server and hosted applications usages will also impact server performance. So check those points also.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the top option is one of the very new, very fast and capable Skylake-SP Xeons - they're lovely

Answer (score 0):

Run (a simulation of) your workload on each and see the response time and throughput.

CPU is not always everything for performance. There are many variables, try to only change one at a time: storage systems (solid state vs spindles), memory quantity, network throughput and latency, and yes CPU model and clock. Also, beware that over subscription means the physical CPU is probably executing more VMs than just you and won't get its full throughput.